# load static files in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

i am trying to display an default image if the image from the server is not available. the `business.profilePic` is dynamically loaded from the server `onerror` i want to display image from static folder

```
cell1.innerHTML = '{% load static %}<img class="img-responsive" 
src=' + business.profilePic + 'width="60" onerror="this.onerror = null; 
this.src={% static search/GoCheck_Logo.png %}" height="80" alt="Logo">';
```

in html body the `{% load static %}` is working fine but in javascript i don't have any idea how to do this

Comment: try `{% load staticfiles %}` and then `{% static 'search/GoCheck_Logo.png' %}`

Comment: @SancaKembang i tried this `'{% load staticfiles %}<img class="img-responsive" src=' + business.profilePic + 'width="60" onerror="this.onerror = null; this.src="{% static "search/GoCheck_Logo.png" %}"" height="80" alt="Logo">';` but not working

Comment: are you tried it to your `/static/to/file.js`? if yes, of course you can't used it.. the templatetags only intended for your `template.html`